# Finding subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> I need to find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

**My attempt:**

$\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is cyclic $\Longrightarrow$ all the subgroups will be also cyclic, according to Lagrangh the order of the nontrivial sugroups will be: $2,4,5,10$

So the subgroups will be:$\color{blue}{\{10,20\},\{5,10,15,20\},\{4,8,12,16,20\},\{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20\}}$

> Is it correct? is there other methods to solve this? any hints please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You left out the sugroups $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb Z_{20}$ but otherwise you are right. Cyclic groups of order $n$ have exactly one subgroup of each order that divides $n$. (In fact if a subgroup of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of each order dividing $n$ then it is cyclic, although that is not so relevant to this question).